# what's the difference between two method below? just one line code difference

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying a simple quicksort. However, I have two nearly identical methods (partition1 & partition2). The only difference between the two is one line of code, specifically in solution1 I use `i = l` and `i+=1` after swap. Alternatively, in solution2 I use `i = l-1`. Can someone tell me why they behave so differently?

Solution 1:

```
     def partition1(x, l, r):
        tmp = x[r]
        i = l
        j = l
        while j<= r -1:
            if x[j] <= tmp:
                x[j], x[i] = x[i], x[j]
                i+=1
            j+=1
        x[i+1], x[r] = x[r], x[i+1]
        return i+1
```

Solution 2:

```
    def partition2(x, l, r):
        tmp = x[r]
        i = l-1
        j = l
        while j<= r -1:
            if x[j] <= tmp:
                i+=1
                x[j], x[i] = x[i], x[j]
            j+=1
        x[i+1], x[r] = x[r], x[i+1]
        return i+1
```

The actual sort function:

```
    def quicksort(x, left, right):
        if left < right:
            p = partition1(x, left, right)
            if left < p:
                quicksort(x, left, p-1)
            if p < right:
                quicksort(x, p+1, right)

    arr =[12, 0, 9, 1, 8, 22, 10, 45, 32, 33, 40]
    print quicksort(arr, 0, len(arr)-1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because, after the `while`, `i` is at the position of the last swap in solution 2 but one step further in solution 1.

To fix it in solution 1, you have to change the last two lines to:

```
x[i], x[r] = x[r], x[i]
return i
```